# Is there a way to partially apply getLine?

Tags: haskell, partial-application

Is there a way to partially apply `getLine` to `writeFile` or a similar function (for file naming purposes)? I want to do something like this:

```
main = writeFile ??? . computeSomething =<< somethingElse
```

`???` should be a line entered by the user to name the output file but I have no idea what to insert for `???`. I tried inserting `=<< getLine` and similar snippets but nothing worked for me.

Is it possible to achieve this without using do-notation in a readable way?

Comment: `writeFile` has two arguments, a path and a string. We get the path from `getLine`, but what's the string to write?

Comment: @AndrásKovács The string is what is returned by ``computeSomething``.

Comment: So, `getLine >>= flip writeFile computeSomething` ?

Comment: @Zeta *facepalm* Yes, thank you. This is a sign I have to take a break ;) Do you want to answer it or should I delete this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flip` to flip the order of arguments:

```
getLine >>= flip writeFile computeSomething
```

The tool [`pointfree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) is helpful if you want to eta-reduce a function.